# Why is mysql query not returning correct amount

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This query keeps returning 2 entries and I can not work out why.

I have a database holding my members in a table called `members`. At the moment it has 5 records as it is just for testing. When I use the following query I get two results, my current id which I am logged into the website with and a blank result.

```
$memarray = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members") or die ("unable to get info");
$fArray = mysql_fetch_array($memarray);

echo count($fArray);    //shows 2
echo $fArray[0];        //shows '102' my current id
echo $fArray[1];        //shows nothing
```

Comment: can you show the output? and use `msqli_query` instead of `mysql_query`

Comment: added the outputs above thanks

Comment: Do yourself a favor and replace `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*` as `mysql_*` is deprecated.   http://us3.php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_fetch_array()` stores one row in an array. To retrieve all rows, you have to call it repeatedly.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    ...
}
```

---

To store all rows in an array, simply do

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $rows[] = $row;
```

This, however, is rather inefficient. If possible, you should process your data within the `while`-loop.

Comment: Thanks. can i ask how i could push each value into a new array to hold all the ids? thanks

Answer (score 0):

By using `mysql_fetch_array($memarray)` you get the first row from the query result.
The default second parameter for the function is "MYSQL_BOTH".
This means you get [0=>'someID', 'id'=>"someID"]
You can use "MYSQL_ASSOC" instead.
See this [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as **an associative array, a numeric array**, or both
http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

```
$memarray = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members") or die ("unable to get info");
$fArray = mysql_fetch_array($memarray);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($fArray);
```

result would be some thing like this :

```
Array ( [0] => 23 [id] => 23 )
```

obviously count($fArray) returns 2

to count all recors

```
$memarray = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM members") or die ("unable to get info");
$fArray = mysql_fetch_assoc($memarray);
echo $fArray['count'];
```

or

```
$memarray = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members") or die ("unable to get info");
echo mysql_num_rows($memarray);
```

to fetch all your records

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($memarray))
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

and I also suggest take look at this notice :‌

> **Warning** This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension
> should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ
> for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
> mysqli_fetch_array() PDOStatement::fetch()

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$memarray = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM members") or die ("unable to get info");
while ($fArray = mysqli_fetch_array($memarray))
{
   echo $fArray["id"];
}
```